# application pools keeps stopping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pool

I have an issue with SharePoint server, I hope you can help me solve it.

here is my question

I deployed SharePoint 2019 (on Windows server 2019) and SQL 2017(on Windows server 2019),

Since I deployed the environment, I encountered this issue once in a while and I tried many solutions and only solution that worked  was repair option in SharePoint 2019 setup.

Here are symptoms:

SharePoint 80 pool and central administration pool has stopped.

SharePoint timer service stopped and I got 1503 error when I tried to restart it.

I got message when I opened SharePoint management shell.
[image]

Note : when I deployed the SharePoint server I use local administrator account instead of using sp-farm account. 
can this  issue relate the account that I' m used in deployment stage or no ,and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the local administrator account to install SharePoint 2019. Please try to change the credential in the application pool to your farm account. And change all service accounts in your farm to the domain farm account or other domain accounts you plan to use as service accounts.

If you just start the work, it may be better to re-install SharePoint server in the correct process. [Reference link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/install-for-sharepoint-server-2019)

Comment: so only changes    will be in IIS.?

Comment: @Amal,IIS is the first need. All the service accounts you use in your SharePoint farm is also needed to be changed.